# Do these diagrams on Complementary Distribution contradict each other?

Tags: compl-distribution

Does the [diagram on left](https://blogonlinguistics.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/phoneme-sound-allophone-phone/) contradict [diagram on right](https://www.departments.bucknell.edu/linguistics/lectures/05lect06.html)? Which is correct?

I think there's a contradiction because  the right diagram answers an unequivocal no, but the left diagram answers Yes and No, to the right same question.

[image]

Comment: There is no contradiction. Questions are different.

Comment: And, the one on the right takes 'complementary distribution' to mean allophony (in my experience this is often how the term is used). The diagram on the left however takes 'complementary ditribution' to be merely a description of the facts, needing further interrogation to determine if the sounds are actually allophones or not (as with English /h/ and /ŋ/ — a pretty rare situation as far as I know).